# how to log using systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, logs

given a systemd service file: `envoy-ratelimit.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=envoy-ratelimit
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/envoy-ratelimit
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/ratelimit $OPTIONS
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=envoy-ratelimit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and its arguments `/etc/sysconfig/envoy-ratelimit`

```
OPTIONS=""
RUNTIME_SUBDIRECTORY=ratelimit
LOG_LEVEL=info
PORT=8082
GRPC_PORT=8081
REDIS_SOCKET_TYPE=tcp
REDIS_URL=127.0.0.1:6389
USE_STATSD=false
```

when I run the ratelimit service via a command I can see the logs:

```
# RUNTIME_SUBDIRECTORY=ratelimit PORT=8082 REDIS_SOCKET_TYPE=tcp REDIS_URL=172.31.141.233:6389 LOG_LEVEL=WARN USE_STATSD=false /usr/local/sbin/ratelimit 
WARN[0000] statsd is not in use                         
WARN[0000] connecting to redis on tcp 172.31.141.233:6389 with pool size 10 
WARN[0000] Listening for HTTP on ':8082'                
WARN[0000] Listening for debug on ':6070'               
WARN[0000] Listening for gRPC on ':8081'
```

when I run the above as a systemd service, can somebody advise where the logs appear ?

```
# systemctl status envoy-ratelimit.service 
● envoy-ratelimit.service - envoy-ratelimit
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/envoy-ratelimit.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-10-28 22:37:04 CET; 5s ago
  Process: 22110 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22161 (ratelimit)
   CGroup: /system.slice/envoy-ratelimit.service
           └─22161 /usr/local/sbin/ratelimit
# journalctl -f -u envoy-ratelimit
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-03-16 05:00:02 CET. --

^C
```

`/var/log/messages` is also empty of logging from `envoy-ratelimit`

Comment: Seeing that you specify `StandardOutput=syslog`, did you check `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: there is no `/var/log/syslog`, CentOS 7 is what I am using, it is `/var/log/messages` but no luck :(

Comment: You'll probably want to use `journal` instead of `syslog`. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=

Comment: changing `StandardOutput` `StandardError` to `journal` still has no effect

Comment: If you run `journalctl` by normal user, not root? What does it happen?

Comment: same thing, empty output

Comment: Did you execute `systemctl daemon-reload` after making your change?

Comment: yes, I cannot restart the service if I don;'t reload systemd first, as it detects the modification fo the files